# XSLT 1 Grouping and combining IDs to csv

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I have the following XML document and like to group the books by the group tag and combine all IDs (titles) of a group to a csv using Java and **XSLT 1**.

I furthermore like to have a summary element containing all shared information of a book series (SeriesInfo) as well as two elements in each group; one (e.g. Titles) containing all titles (IDs) of this group comma separated (csv) and one (e.g. AnyTitle) containing any title (which one does not matter, first or last is fine).

I've managed to do the grouping by Muenchian Grouping but don't know how to get the csv and the any element. I've done some research on this, but the solutions I found were either extremely specific or using XSLT 2 or higher.

Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Books>

    <Book>
        <Title>Harry Potter and the philosopher's stone</Title>
        <Group>Harry Potter</Group>
        <Author>J.K.R.</Author>
        <Pages>650</Pages>
    </Book>

    <Book>
        <Title>Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets</Title>
        <Group>Harry Potter</Group>
        <Author>J.K.R.</Author>
        <Pages>700</Pages>
    </Book>

    <Book>
        <Title>Lord of the Rings complete edition</Title>
        <Group>Lord of the Rings</Group>
        <Author>J.R.R. Tolkien</Author>
        <Pages>2500</Pages>
    </Book>

</Books>
```

Destination XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Serieses>

    <Series>
        <Group>Harry Potter</Group>
        <Titles>Harry Potter and the philosopher's stone,Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets</Titles>
        <AnyTitle>Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets</AnyTitle>

        <Books>
            <Book>
                <Title>Harry Potter and the philosopher's stone</Title>
                <Group>Harry Potter</Group>
                <Pages>650</Pages>
            </Book>

            <Book>
                <Title>Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets</Title>
                <Group>Harry Potter</Group>
                <Pages>700</Pages>
            </Book>
        </Books>

        <SeriesInfo>
            <Author>J.K.R.</Author>
            <Group>Harry Potter</Group>
        </SeriesInfo>
    </Series>

    <Series>
        <Group>Lord of the Rings</Group>
        <Titles>Lord of the Rings complete edition</Titles>
        <AnyTitle>Lord of the Rings complete edition</AnyTitle>

        <Books>
            <Book>
                <Title>Lord of the Rings complete edition</Title>
                <Group>Lord of the Rings</Group>
                <Pages>2500</Pages>
            </Book>
        </Books>

        <SeriesInfo>
            <Author>J.R.R. Tolkien</Author>
            <Group>Lord of the Rings</Group>
        </SeriesInfo>
    </Series>

</Serieses>
```

Using the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="book-by-name" match="Book" use="Group" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Books">
        <Serieses>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="Book[generate-id() = generate-id(key('book-by-name', Group)[1])]"
                mode="group" />
        </Serieses>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Book" mode="group">
        <Series>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Group" />

            <Books>
                <xsl:apply-templates
                    select="key('book-by-name', Group)" />
            </Books>

            <SeriesInfo>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Author" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="Group" />
            </SeriesInfo>

        </Series>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Book">
        <Book>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="node()[self::Title|self::Group|self::Pages]" />
        </Book>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was able to get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Serieses>

    <Series>
        <Group>Harry Potter</Group>

        <Books>
            <Book>
                <Title>Harry Potter and the philosopher's stone</Title>
                <Group>Harry Potter</Group>
                <Pages>650</Pages>
            </Book>

            <Book>
                <Title>Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets</Title>
                <Group>Harry Potter</Group>
                <Pages>700</Pages>
            </Book>
        </Books>

        <SeriesInfo>
            <Author>J.K.R.</Author>
            <Group>Harry Potter</Group>
        </SeriesInfo>
    </Series>

    <Series>
        <Group>Lord of the Rings</Group>

        <Books>
            <Book>
                <Title>Lord of the Rings complete edition</Title>
                <Group>Lord of the Rings</Group>
                <Pages>2500</Pages>
            </Book>
        </Books>

        <SeriesInfo>
            <Author>J.R.R. Tolkien</Author>
            <Group>Lord of the Rings</Group>
        </SeriesInfo>
    </Series>

</Serieses>
```

Using any more recent version of XSLT is not really helpful to me because I need to rely on the standard library.

**EDIT:**
Clearified what I meant by any title: Doesn't really matter, first or last is fine.

Comment: What exactly does "any title" mean? If the group contains a number of books, how do you decide which book's title to choose?

Comment: Any title means literally anyone which can be arbitrarily chosen. For me it doesn't matter which title it is (first, last, randomly chosen); I just need anyone. First/Last seems to make most sense to me, but is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="book-by-group" match="Book" use="Group" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Books">
    <Serieses>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Book[generate-id() = generate-id(key('book-by-group', Group)[1])]" mode="group" />
    </Serieses>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Book" mode="group">
    <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('book-by-group', Group)" />
    <Series>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Group" />
        <Titles>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$current-group" mode="Title"/>
        </Titles>
        <AnyTitle>
            <xsl:value-of select="$current-group[1]/Title"/>
        </AnyTitle>
        <Books>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$current-group" />
        </Books>
        <SeriesInfo>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Author" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Group" />
        </SeriesInfo>
    </Series>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Book">
    <Book>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Title | Group| Pages" />
    </Book>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Book" mode="Title">
    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

This populates the `Titles` element with a comma-separated list of the group's titles. For the `AnyTitle` element, I chose the title of the first book in the group.

---

Personally, I would prefer to shorten the whole thing to:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="book-by-group" match="Book" use="Group" />

<xsl:template match="/Books">
    <Serieses>
        <xsl:for-each select="Book[generate-id() = generate-id(key('book-by-group', Group)[1])]">
            <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('book-by-group', Group)" />
            <Series>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Group" />
                <Titles>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$current-group">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Titles>
                <AnyTitle>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$current-group[1]/Title"/>
                </AnyTitle>
                <Books>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$current-group">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="Title | Group| Pages" />
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Books>
                <SeriesInfo>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Author" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Group" />
                </SeriesInfo>
            </Series>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Serieses>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solutions omit the last title, so they produce

`<Titles>Harry Potter and the philosopher's stone,</Titles>` instead of `<Titles>Harry Potter and the philosopher's stone,Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets</Titles>`.

However by setting the `test="position() != last()"` test condition to always true like `2 != 1` I get `<Titles>Harry Potter and the philosopher's stone,Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets,</Titles>` which is totaly fine because I can truncate the last comma.

Comment: I don't see the results that you report: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuPd, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuPd/1

Comment: I use Java's default implementation (javax.xml.transform.Transformer). Maybe it is a bit different from other implementations. However, your solution obviously seems to be right.